# Changing CSS image by JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to incorporate an Adblock detecter that will display one image when Adblock is detected and another when Adblock isn't detected. The only problem is that the image is displayed and formatted by CSS. So is there a way to change the image that CSS displays through js?

html:

```
<div id="adblockFrame">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/advertisement.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.getElementById("TestAdBlock") != undefined)
    {
        document.getElementById('adblockFrame').innerHTML="<img src='images/ImageHolderno.png'      alt='no adblock' />";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('adblockFrame').innerHTML="<img src='ImageHolderyes.png' alt='Adblock detected!' />";
    }
```

Bear in mind that the image place holders and void and do not serve a purpose as the image is defined by CSS.

CSS:

```
#mainPicture .picture
{
position:relative;
width:650px;
height:325px;
top:10px;
background-image:url(../images/minibg1.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Add a class to the element and act on that in the CSS.

Comment: You could set up two similar CSS classes and switch it with javascript instead of trying to alter a property of a single CSS class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS:

```
document.getElementById('adblockFrame').className = 'adblockersSuck';
```

CSS:

```
.adblockersSuck {
    background:url(ImageHolderyes.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Or insert it dynamically with pseudo-elements:

```
.adblockersSuck:after {
    content:url(ImageHolderyes.png);
}
```

Comment: How would I incorporate the third section 'pseudo-elements'

Comment: [Start reading here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements).

Comment: Ok i've got the two images to show based on the output of the js. The only problem is that when Adblock is enabled the image shows behind the Adblock is disabled image and  isn't in the right place.

Comment: You can put any style you want on the pseudoelement - including `position:relative`, `z-index:1` and `top:-50px`.